# TCL: check if variable is list

Tags: list, variables, tcl

```
set var1 A

set var2 {A}
```

Is it possible to check if variable is list in TCL? For `var1` and `var2` `llength` gives `1`. I am thinking that these 2 variables are considered same. They are both lists with 1 element. Am I right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those two things are considered to be entirely identical, and will produce identical bytecode (except for any byte offsets used for indicating where the content of constants are location, which is not information normally exposed to scripts at all so you can ignore it, plus the obvious differences due to variable names). Semantically, braces are a quoting mechanism and not an indicator of a list (or a script, or …)

You need to write your code to not assume that it can look things up by inspecting the type of a value. The type of `123` could be many different things, such as an integer, a list (of length 1), a unicode string or a command name. Tcl's semantics are based on you *not* asking what the type of a value is, but rather just using commands and having them coerce the values to the right type as required. Tcl's different to many other languages in this regard.

Because of this different approach, it's not easy to answer questions about this in general: the answers get too long with all the different possible cases to be considered *in general* yet most of it will be irrelevant to what you're really seeking to do. Ask about something specific though, and we'll be able to tell you much more easily.

Answer (score 5):

You can try `string is list $var1` but that will accept both of these forms - it will only return false on something that can't syntactically be interpreted as a list, eg. because there is an unmatched bracket like "aa { bb".